# Why is the size of a function in C always 1 byte?

Tags: c, function, size, sizeof

When we check the size of a function using `sizeof()`, we always get **1 byte**.
What does this 1 byte signify?

Answer (score 81):

It's a constraint violation, and your compiler *should* diagnose it. If it compiles it in spite of that, your program has undefined behaviour [thanks to @Steve Jessop for the clarification of the failure mode, and see [@Michael Burr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259995/596781) for why some compilers allow this]: From C11, 6.5.3.4./1:

> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type

Comment: That's a constraint, which means in a conforming compiler it's diagnosed. If the compiler compiles it anyway (having diagnosed it), then behavior is undefined. If the compiler doesn't diagnose it (which for example gcc doesn't without `-pedantic`), you have a non-conforming compiler and *every* program has undefined behavior.

Comment: @SteveJessop: This is really strange: If this were on the same level as a *syntax error*, as Michael Burr suggests, then how come the compiler is really reluctant to diagnose this? I have to say `-pedantic` to GCC to get it to speak up.

Comment: The behavior puts it in the same category as a GNU C extension, but I have no idea why anyone *wants* that behavior, so I don't know why the GNU authors went out of their way to add it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Note that this is even with `-std=c11`, *not* `gnu11`. This is a really weird compiler extension.

Comment: Ooh! I bet it's to enable arithmetic on function pointers, the same way that `sizeof(void)` is 1 in GNU C.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Ah, yes, that explains why that extension would seem desirable. Good stuff.

Comment: Regarding `-std=c11`: someone should refer the `-std=c*` options to Advertising Standards. They don't enable conformance mode, they merely disable extensions that would prevent a well-formed program from compiling (such as `typeof` being a keyword, since a well-formed C program can use it as a variable name, but `gcc` by default would reject that). To additionally disable extensions that allow ill-formed programs to pass undiagnosed, you need `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: Implementations, not compilers, are conforming or not conforming. gcc with -pedantic is a different implementation from gcc without -pedantic.

Answer (score 56):

This is not undefined behavior - the C language standard requires a diagnostic when using the `sizeof` operator with a function designator (a function name) since it's a constraint violation for the `sizeof` operator.

However, as an extension to the C language, GCC allows arithmetic on `void` pointers and function pointers, which is done by treating the size of a `void` or a function as `1`.  As a consequence, the `sizeof` operator will evaluate to `1` for `void` or a function with GCC.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith

You can get GCC to issue a warning when using `sizeof` with these operands by using the `-pedantic` or `-Wpointer-arith` options to GCC. Or make it an error with `-Werror=pointer-arith`.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. C requires diagnostic messages for some, but not all UB. You can't state that something has defined behavior just because there's a diagnostic.

Comment: C requires a diagnostic for all constraint violations (5.1.1.3 Diagnostics in C99 or C11). A constraint (3.8 in C99/C11) is a "restriction, either syntactic or semantic, by which the exposition of language elements is to be interpreted", which seems to say that something that doesn't follow the constraints can't be interpreted.

Comment: And to be clear - a constraint violation doesn't result in undefined behavior.  It's an error, like a syntax error. For example, the standard says, "if a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears **outside of a constraint** is violated, the behavior is undefined".  If a constraint violation would result in UB, why would the standard talk about only the "shalls" and "shall nots" that aren't in constraints here?

Comment: Indeed. But again you can't invert that logic. You can't say that every diagnostic is a constraint violation. In fact, it's been observed that strictly speaking, a compiler may emit a "this line could be incorrect" diagnostic for _every_ line of code and nothing else.

Comment: @MSalters: it's a constraint violation because it's the "Constraints" section of the `sizeof` operator's description that says `sizeof` cannot be applied to a function type.  That's what makes this a constraint violation (and therefore an error that requires a diagnostic).

Comment: Sure, not arguing that. But you state that it's **not** UB because the categories "Constraint Violation" and "UB" are orthogonal, because the former results in a diagnostic (and presumably the latter doesn't). That logic is flawed. UB can cause a diagnostic (anything can), therefore the categories are not orthogonal.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: How come the OP *doesn't* get a diagnostic then?

Comment: I really didn't state much of anything about UB except that `sizeof` a function isn't UB (which I mentioned pretty much only because other answers stated it was UB). But perhaps I muddled that because of the way I structured the sentence. To be more clear. `sizeof` a function is not UB (as several answers have claimed). It is a constraint violation. As such, it requires a diagnostic. GCC permits it as an extension.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the OP doesn't get a diagnostic because presumably they are using GCC, which permits this use as a C language extension.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: OK, thanks. I've edited my answer to make it more accurate.

Comment: Requiring a diagnostic doesn't mean that the code must not compile, does it? A warning is a kind of diagnostic. After issuing the diagnostic, I'd say that the value of this is implementation-defined, just as the value of `sizeof(int)` is implementation-defined (the standard only defines the size of `char` -- other data types have minimum sizes, but not standard sizes).

Comment: @Barmar: a diagnostic doesn't necessarily mean an error, but a constraint violation is on the order of a syntax error - see my first comment above.  So if you don't get an error from the compiler on a constraint violation, that would be a similar situation to a compiler not giving an error on the following: `int x = "abc" << "123";`  I suppose it's possible that you might find a compiler that will only issue a warning for that.

Comment: But if the compiler has added a meaning for it as an extension (as GCC has in this case), it wouldn't make sense for it to generate a fatal error, but a warning might still be appropriate.

Comment: Yes - if the compiler provides something useful/intended as an extension then it certainly wouldn't make sense to produce an error.  The point I'm trying to get across is that this isn't undefined behavior. It's either an error (when following a bog-standard spec) or it acts according to some non-standard language extension (as in this case with GCC). But this doesn't fall into the 'anything goes' category of UB.

Comment: 'Requiring a diagnostic doesn't mean that the code must not compile, does it?' -- What the implementation does beyond issuing a diagnostic is beyond the scope of the standard. It could bring about world peace or destroy the planet -- the standard doesn't say.

Comment: 'C requires diagnostic messages for some, but not all UB' -- this is false; the standard does not require a diagnostic for any UB ... it does not require anything at all, that being the whole point of it being *undefined* behavior. It's also moot, as the answer makes no claims at all about any instance of UB.

Answer (score 13):

It signifies that the compiler writer decided on a value of 1 rather than make demons fly from your nose (indeed, it was another undefined use of `sizeof` that gave us that expression: "the C compiler itself MUST issue a diagnostic IF this is the first required diagnostic resulting from your program, and then MAY itself cause demons to fly from your nose (which, by the way, could well BE the documented diagnostic message) just as it MAY issue further diagnostics for further violations of syntax rules or constraints (or, for that matter, for any reason it chooses)." https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/comp.std.c/ycpVKxTZkgw/S2hHdTbv4d8J

From this there's slang term "nasal demons" for whatever a compiler decides to do in response to an undefined construct. `1` is the nasal demon of this compiler for this case.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'll have to admit though, that there's a reason most of my answers on C (and C++) are either on general language-agnostic principles or historical nuggets like that. My C experience is bordering on historical in itself :)

Answer (score 7):

As others pointed out, sizeof() can take any valid identifier, but it won't return a valid (an honestly true and valid) result for function names. Furthermore, it definitely may, or may not, result in "demons out of nose" syndrome.

If you want to profile your program function size, check the linker map, which can be found on the intermediate results directory (the one where things are compiled into .obj/.o or where the resulting image/executable lays). Sometimes there's an option to generate or not this map file... it's compiler/linker dependent.

If you wanted the size of a pointer to a function, they're all the same size, the size of an addressing word on your cpu.

Comment: What sort of statement is "it definitely may or may not"??? Isn't that true of literally everything?

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, but here it may or may not do anything, and still be within the rules. It's true a compiler may or may not refuse to compile `int x = 1;` but only one of those is allowed for a standards compliant compiler. With `sizeof()` being applied to a function, it may or may not return a set value, or refuse to compile, or return a random value based on whatever's in a particular register at the time. Literal nasal demons are unlikely, but within the letter of the standard.

Comment: @kerrek It may be true for nothing or may not be false for anything... look at it as being fuzzy illogical.

Comment: If you want to know the size of a pointer to a function, apply `sizeof` to a pointer to a function.