# using sizeof () to find function type length in ANSI C

Tags: c, sizeof

When I need to find function type length, I used to sizeof () to do it.

The expected result is 4 bytes and 8 bytes, but now, the result is 1 byte through GCC.

why the output is 1 byte, not 4 bytes and 8 bytes?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo (); 
double bar (); 

int 
main (void)
{
    printf ("int foo () %lu\n", sizeof (foo));  
    printf ("double bar () %lu\n", sizeof (bar));
}

double 
bar (void)
{
    return 1.1;
}

int
foo (void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` is only well-defined on object types.

Comment: Compile using `-Wpointer-arith` and see

Comment: Get a habit of running GCC with `-pedantic-errors` command-line option. Always. Omit `-pedantic-errors` only of you have a very very very good reason to do so.

Comment: @P0W, that's a great link - one of the answers even has a plausible reason for why it works this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the standard says *"The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type"* (§6.5.3.4/1), in GNU C, the result of doing this is well defined:

> ***"`sizeof` is also allowed on void and on function types, and returns 1"***
>   ~ [GCC, 6.23 Arithmetic on void- and Function-Pointers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith)

Also have a look at: [Why is the size of a function in C always 1 byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12259101/1168156)

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` operator shall not be used on function types, this is explicitly forbidden by ISO/IEC C standard. So returned value has no meaning.

Reference **ISO/IEC 9899:201x §6.5.3.4**:

> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member.

I guess that enabling `-pedantic` flag should raise a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find the size of the function itself not its return value. In order to find the type of the return value, you need to add a pair of parentheses to tell the compiler that you need the type of the function call expression, like this:

```
printf ("int foo () %lu\n", sizeof (foo()));  
printf ("double bar () %lu\n", sizeof (bar()));
```

Note that the functions are *not* going to be called: the sizeof of their return type will be figured out at compile time.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/IZz2oC).

Answer (score 0):

The sizeof should not be applied to a variable that has a function type. So, what you are seeing is basically an undefined behavior. Ideally the compiler should have complained about it..

Answer (score 0):

Applying `sizeof` to a function name is a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic from any conforming compiler. gcc is not conforming by default, but can be made (nearly) so with the right command-line options, such as:

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic
```

(replace `c99` by `c90` or `c11` if you like).

gcc has an extension that permits pointer arithmetic on `void*` and on function pointers. (Such extensions are permitted by the ISO standard, but a conforming compiler must still diagnose any constraint violations.) Adding 1 to a function pointer, for example, advances it by 1 byte.

Unfortunately, IMHO, the gcc developers chose to do this by giving functions and the `void` type a size of 1. The behavior of pointer arithmetic follows from that, but it has the drawback that attempts to compute the size of a function or of a void expression are not rejected.

Standard C does not provide a way to determine the size of a function; it doesn't even discuss such a concept. gcc, as far as I know, doesn't provide an extension to do so; `sizeof func` yields a fictitious value of 1, not anything related to the code size of the function.

You can always determine the size of a function *pointer*, which will typically be 4 or 8 bytes, but of course that's not the size of the function itself. And you can't do that by applying `sizeof` to the function name.

If a C program could obtain the size of a function (presumably the size of the code that implements it), I can't think of anything useful it could do with that information other than display it. If that's the information you're looking for, you might examine an assembly listing or an object file. For example, on a Unix-like system, the output of `nm foo.o` shows the address of each function; that can usually tell you the size of the code for each function (except perhaps for the last one).  This is all extremely system-specific.